# Mac Montery 12.4- nslookup ok, ping won't work to name, but OK to IP address

Tags: network, dns

I have tried:
`sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`; `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

I had a Brave web browser open overnight and it still works!  Using it here.
I had a Firefox web browser open, no longer works.
Command-line-  I do `nslookup www.ibm.com` and it is fine.  I can ping the address of this site, but I can't ping the URL-`ping: cannot resolve www.ibm.com.: Unknown host`

I'm afraid if I reboot, I'll lose my Brave browser access, and thus my email access.

I have tried both wired Ethernet to a firewall, as well as wireless direct to the router that is part of my DSL modem with the same results.  I have a 5G gateway that I've connected to wirelessly and it gives the same results.

Comment: Thanks for the edits/updates!   I got caught up on work yesterday and rebooted my Mac.  It is now working.  Hope this doesn't recur, and if it does, that a reboot is all that is needed...